# Complex attributes in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I need to associate my products with "complex attribute".

By complex attribute I mean not only "attribute = value".

I need to store a couple of values for each attributes.

Let's say I've an attribute "manufacturer"

I need to store possible values as "id: 1 - name: Nike" and "id: 2 - name: Reebok".

Is it possible to do that? Note that I need to be able to filter that then...

The id is important to me because it is generated by another application and then synchronized with Magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your question. But i think what you need is to choose a new attribute and select **Dropdown** on the input type.

You can use position as your ID.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields and go to  Creating an attribute with controlled options - Manufacturer

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, you're close to what I want. But what I would have like is to be able to fetch my products by filtering using the id where I want to display the name, BUT I need to be able to set the id myself because it is related to another external tool